# Slide Out Form CSS Positioning

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have found a tutorial in the net that will met my form slide up and down.

The only problem is it's located to the left. I want to position it to the right.

Here's the LINK to the [DEMO](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/slideout_feedback_form/)

Here's the code from the tutorial

```
.feedback {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.feedback a {
   display: block;
   height: 20px;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   background: red;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   outline: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
   padding: 5px;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

And i tried changing the `left:0` to `right:0` and the `float:left` to `float:right`

It actually works on Firefox. But when i test it in chrome the FORM breaks down and moves far away to the right...

HELP and Thanks!

Comment: feedback as is, is not a valid selector. You'll need to target it as a class (.feedback).

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing the `left:0` for `right:0` should do the work. I've tested it with the example you provided in chrome.
The resulting class styles are:

```
.feedback {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

## UPDATE

I've noticed the previous solution fails when hiding and trying to show again the form.
To solve it:

```
.feedback {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 482px;  /*changed*/
}

.feedback a {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #F00;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    outline: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;   /*changed*/
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```